# Stack Overflow Error, with setInterval in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I keep running into a stack overflow error in a timer that I am creating with Vue and I don't get why?

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here:

In my template:

```
<span class="coundown-number">  {{ minutesRemaining }} : {{ secondsRemaining }}</span>
<span v-if="countdownDone">DONE</span>
<button v-if="running" class="custom-button" type="button" @click="runCountdown(countdownTime)">Start</button>
<input class="set-time" type="number" v-model="countdownTime" placeholder="Enter a Time in Minutes">
```

Here is my js:

```
export default {
  name: 'Countdown',
  props: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      running: true,
      countdownTime: null,
      remainingTime: null,
      countdownDone: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    minutesRemaining() {
      return (this.remainingTime - (this.remainingTime % 60)) / 60;
    },
    secondsRemaining() {
      return this.remainingTime % 60;
    },

  },
  methods: {
    runCountdown(timerTime) {
      let currentTime = timerTime*60;
      this.remainingTime = currentTime;
      if (currentTime > 0){
        currentTime--;
        setInterval(this.runCountdown(this.currentTime), 1000);
      }
      else{
        this.countdownDone = true;
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

I think the problem is that I call the `setInterval` function within the same function it is created. But I do it as it is because I don't know how else to initiate it.

If it was defined somewhere (I don't know where) as `let tick = setInterval(runCountdown, 1000)` how would I even be able to call it onclick? I appreciate a solution for sure, but definitely would like some help understanding the overall concept that you think I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is here:

```
runCountdown(timerTime) {
  let currentTime = timerTime*60;
  this.remainingTime = currentTime;
  if (currentTime > 0){
    currentTime--;
    setInterval(this.runCountdown(this.currentTime), 1000); // this line
  }
  else{
    this.countdownDone = true;
  }   
}
```

You're not passing the function as a callback, you're invoking it immediately, infinitely.

You need to call it inside a callback in the `setInterval` function.

```
setInterval(() => { this.runCountdown(this.currentTime) }, 1000);
```

Although `setInterval` will call this function multiple times, exponentially, I think you might want to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead.

```
setTimeout(() => { this.runCountdown(this.currentTime) }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Phiter's answer did address the main question I had, however the code doesn't work because there is one other major logic issue.

Here is my logic mistake:

```
methods: {
    runCountdown(timerTime) {
      let currentTime = timerTime*60;
      this.remainingTime = currentTime;
      if (currentTime > 0){
        currentTime--;
        setInterval(this.runCountdown(this.currentTime), 1000);
      }
      else{
        this.countdownDone = true;
      }   
    }
```

`runCountdown` was accepting `timerTime` in minutes and then converting it to seconds on the second line of code.

This meant that every time I made a callback to `runCountdown` from `setInterval` I would multiply `timerTime` by 60 to convert it to seconds. However, it was already in seconds.

So, if I passed 1 minute to start; it would be converted to 60 seconds and subtract 1; making its new value 59. When `setInterval` called `runCountdown` again it would pass the current value of `currentTime` or in this case 59. Well, multiply 59*60 you get 3540 then 3540-1=3539. Run the function again: 3539 * 60 - 1 and again and again to infinity and beyond.

Got it? Good - cause I clearly didn't!

How did I solve this? I created a computed property, `countdownInSeconds`, to convert the user's original minute input to seconds. Then passed this `onclick` to `runCountdown`

Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="countdown">
    <h1>How long would you like to study for?</h1>
      <span class="countdown-number">  
        {{ minutesRemaining }} : {{ secondsRemaining }}</span>
        <span v-if="countdownDone">DONE</span>
      <button v-if="running" class="custom-button" type="button" 
            @click="runCountdown(countdownInSeconds)">
         Start
      </button>
    <input class="set-time" type="number" v-model="countdownTime" 
      placeholder="Enter a Time in Minutes"> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Countdown',
  props: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      running: true,
      countdownTime: null,
      remainingTime: null,
      countdownDone: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    countdownInSeconds(){
      return this.countdownTime * 60;
    },
    minutesRemaining() {
      return (this.remainingTime - (this.remainingTime % 60)) / 60;
    },
    secondsRemaining() {
      return this.remainingTime % 60;
    },

  },
  methods: {
    runCountdown(timerTime) {
      // assign the remainingTime to the current seconds to allow for allow for computed properties to access this loop
      this.remainingTime = timerTime;
      // if the timer time is still above 0, keep running the loop; will also need to check to see if time has been
      // paused, reset or changed
      if (timerTime > 0){
        timerTime--;
        setTimeout(() => {this.runCountdown(timerTime)}, 1000);
      }
      else{
        this.countdownDone = true;
      }   
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Hopefully, this helps ya!!